# Error Undefined Offset 0 al actualizar registro, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

resulta que estoy teniendo un problemita a la hora de actualizar registros en laravel, el contexto es que en mi vista tengo un formulario con 3 option radio en el cual un usuario debe seleccionar una opcion, luego hacia la vista de edicion devuelvo el mismo formulario pero con los datos que vienen desde la bd, pero a la hora de cambiar la opcion en estos input me arroja error Ofsset 0....

En el request me llega la data de esos input asi: clasgen":{"1":"mejorable"}

Si reviso en la bd, los registros que he actualizado estan guardados asi:
{"1":"mejorable"}

En el controlador tengo esa seccion del update asi:

```
 //Actualiza en tabla ejecucion_mantenimientos
        $ejecucion = EjecucionMantenimiento::find($id);
        $ejecucion->clasificacion_general = $request->get('clasgen')[0];
```

Y en la vista la seccion de los inputs la tengo asi (vista de edicion):

```
 <!--TABLA VALORACION 1-->
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <table class="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                      <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">MUY DEFICIENTE</th>
                                        <th scope="col">DEFICIENTE</th>
                                        <th scope="col">MEJORABLE</th>
                                      </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td  class="uno">
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input type="radio" name="clasgen[{{$ejecucion->id}}]" {{ ($ejecucion->clasificacion_general =="muy_deficiente")? "checked" : "" }} value="muy_deficiente" >
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input type="radio" name="clasgen[{{$ejecucion->id}}]" {{ ($ejecucion->clasificacion_general =="deficiente")? "checked" : "" }} value="deficiente" >                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input type="radio" name="clasgen[{{$ejecucion->id}}]" {{ ($ejecucion->clasificacion_general =="mejorable")? "checked" : "" }} value="mejorable" >                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                        </div>
```

Saludos a todos

Comment: No entiendo. Por un lado el name parece ser compuesto: `name="clasgen[{{$ejecucion->id}}]"` pero por otro lo llamas sin el id de ejecución así: `$request->get('clasgen')[0];` ... ¿no será eso el fallo?

Comment: es que si en el controller lo dejo asi: $request->get('clasgen') en la base de datos el campo me lo guarda asi: {"1":"mejorable"} y obviamente al cargar de nuevo la edicion no hay ningun input seleccionado

Comment: Por cierto, repites el cierre del `</div>` despues del último radio button antes de salir de la última columna.

Comment: me di cuenta del error, lo estaba pasando como un array y en realidad es un solo  valor, no multiples lo que se selecciona, deje el nombre asi: name="clasgen" y ahora al parecer funciona

Comment: Me alegro, bueno es saberlo :-)  Ya me parecia a mi raro eso. Saludos!